# How do you correctly set Swagger examples in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger, openapi

**My goal:**

To correctly set the request examples in the OpenApi JSON document on only the endpoints I annotate with SwaggerRequestExample and not the endpoint response or other endpoints lacking this attribute.

**Expected Result:**

```
"post": {
    "tags": [
      "Address"
    ],
    "requestBody": {
      "content": {
        },
        "application/json": {
          "schema": {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Address"
          },
          "example": {"id":"995ace6e-33d5-4efd-860e-b653fef60dad","binaryAddress":246,"distance":123}
        }
        }
      }
    },
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "Success",
        "content": {
          "application/json": {
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Address"
            }
          }
          }
        }
      }
```

**Actual Result:**

```
"post": {
    "tags": [
      "Address"
    ],
    "requestBody": {
      "content": {
        },
        "application/json": {
          "schema": {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Address"
          },
          "example": {"id":"995ace6e-33d5-4efd-860e-b653fef60dad","binaryAddress":246,"distance":123}
        }
        }
      }
    },
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "Success",
        "content": {
          "application/json": {
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Address"
            },
            "example": {"id":"a04c827c-5e29-4940-8bee-89f8e07af5a8","binaryAddress":246,"distance":123}
          }
          }
        }
      }
```

**Error Messages:**

I haven't encountered any error messages.

**What I've tried:**

I've tried several startup and controller attribute configurations to try and get the expected behavior, but have been unable to get the expected result. This is the configuration I expect to work, but unfortunately is not:

*Startup.cs snippet*

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.MapType<ushort>(() => OpenApiSchemaFactory.MapInteger(typeof(ushort)));
});
services.ConfigureOptions<ConfigureSwaggerOptions>(); // calls .SwaggerExamples()
services.AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport();
services.AddSwaggerExamples();
services.AddSwaggerExamplesFromAssemblyOf<AddressExample>();
```

*AddressController.cs minus other endpoints*

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/v{api-version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class AddressController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Ok(typeof(Address))]
    [BadRequest]
    [SwaggerRequestExample(typeof(Address), typeof(AddressExample))]
    public IActionResult AddAddress([FromBody] Address address)
    {
        return Ok(_service.AddAddress(address)); // The service is just a pass-through layer at the moment
    }
}
```

*AddressExample.cs*

```
public class AddressExample : IExamplesProvider<Address>
{
    public Address GetExamples()
    {
        return new Address
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            BinaryAddress = 246L,
            Distance = 123
        };
    }
}
```

Based on the above code, I'm only expecting the request example to be set. However, the response example is set too. Even more inexplicable to me is that not only that but any endpoint that uses the Address model in either the request or response has the example set as well.

In my attempt to configure this correctly, I discovered that this line

```
services.AddSwaggerExamplesFromAssemblyOf<AddressExample>();
```

Is setting the defined example in all instances of the address model even if I don't use the SwaggerRequestExample attribute annotated on my controller endpoint.

I'm currently at a loss as to how to set the examples with out of the box swagger configuration correctly without creating an example for every instance that the model in question is used.

Can someone point me in the right direction or provide an example that should work? Thanks.

Edit: I will be more than happy to provide additional code as well

Answer (score 6):

I wondered about this too, so I dove into the documentation for [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#include-descriptions-from-xml-comments). It turns out that this is handled via XML Doc comments. Not too long ago this felt very clunky. To start with, you must add XML Doc comments to your API Method. Mine looked like this:

[image]

Then, you need to turn XML Documentation file generation in the properties of your project:

[image]

My test project was called `XcExample.Api.Sometext`. Because I left the 'file path' field blank, when I compiled it placed a file named `XcExample.Api.Sometext.xml` next to the binaries.

Then to include this data in the OAS3/Swagger generation you find the line in your Program.cs that looks like this:
[image]
And you add the file to the generation information like the following:
[image]

Then when you look at the Swagger UI it looks like this:
[image]

Then your OAS doc path section looks like:

```json
"paths": {
    "/api/{id}/GetTogether/{word}/Concat": {
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "Concat"
        ],
        "summary": "Get Some Text Together for a Party",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "id",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "word index",
            "required": true,
            "style": "simple",
            "schema": {
              "type": "integer",
              "format": "int32"
            },
            "example": 9987
          },
          {
            "name": "word",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "indexed word",
            "required": true,
            "style": "simple",
            "schema": {
              "minLength": 2,
              "type": "string"
            },
            "example": "orange"
          }
        ],
        "requestBody": {
          "description": "words and puncuation",
          "content": {
            "application/json": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Sentence"
              }
            },
            "text/json": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Sentence"
              }
            },
            "application/*+json": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Sentence"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success",
            "content": {
              "text/plain": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": {
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                }
              },
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": {
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                }
              },
              "text/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": {
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

The example code is on my [XcExample.Api.Sometext project](https://github.com/Xcaciv/XcExample.Api.Sometext) on github.